# Outlook Spell Checker on MAC

Tags: mac, macos

I am looking for a way to stop sending an email if there are any spelling errors on outlook 2016 Mac. I know you can do this on windows outlook. Can someone please shed some advise on this.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is for Microsoft office in Windows. Not mac OS. I’ve looked up many articles across the web, and it seems check spelling before sending in Outlook for Mac is not available. It is available in the native mail application in Mac OS… Preferences compose check before sending.